# Colouring cells in a gt tables across multiple columns using a column name pattern

Tags: r, gt

Is there any way to colour individual cells in according their values using something like tidyselect syntax? Here I have some `chicken_*` columns and some `ox_*`. Right now I would colour separately in `tab_style` calls:

```r
set.seed(42)
library(tibble)
library(gt)

df <- tibble(
  chicken_mm = runif(10),
  chicken_g = runif(10),
  ox_mm = runif(10),
  ox_g = runif(10)
)


df %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = "#2dc937", alpha = 0.5),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = chicken_mm,
      rows = chicken_g >= 0.5
    )
  ) %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = "#2dc937", alpha = 0.5),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = ox_mm,
      rows = ox_g >= 0.5
    )
  )
```

This works fine but if you have multiple columns it can get really long with a lot of manual steps. Ultimately what I am hoping for is something like this:

```r
df %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = "#2dc937", alpha = 0.5),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = ends_with("_mm"),
      rows = ends_with("_g") >= 0.5
    )
  )
```

Can anyone recommend a good strategy here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use a `for` loop and update the object

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
dfgt <- df %>% 
  gt() 
mm_cols <- grep("_mm$", names(df), value = TRUE)
g_cols <- sub("_mm", "_g", mm_cols)
for(i in seq_along(mm_cols)) {

dfgt <- dfgt %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = "#2dc937", alpha = 0.5),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = mm_cols[i],
      rows = !! rlang::sym(g_cols[i]) >= 0.5
    )
  ) 
  

}
dfgt
```

-output

[image]

Comment: brilliant approach

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this without a loop and want to share. I used map2 to create a list of cells_body objects.

```
set.seed(42)
library(tibble)
library(gt)

df <- tibble(
  chicken_mm = runif(10),
  chicken_g = runif(10),
  ox_mm = runif(10),
  ox_g = runif(10)
)

dfgt <- df %>% 
  gt() 

dfgt2 <- dfgt %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = cell_fill(color = "#2dc937", alpha = 0.5),
    locations = select(df,matches(".*_g")) %>%
      map2(.y = names(select(df,matches(".*_mm"))),
           .f = function(.x,.y) {cells_body(columns = .y,
                                            rows = which(.x >= .5 ))
                                 }
      )
   )
dfgt2
```

Output:
[image]